# Update activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have Activity 1,2 and 3.
When I clicked a button in Activity 1, it will show Activity 2.
When I clicked a button in Activity 2, it will show Activity 3.
Now all the Activity are shown.

When I clicked a button in Activity 3, I want to display an image in Activity 1.
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure about your question you want to go back to Activity1 and display image there.

Comment: you probably need [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)